# Java Generic Method basics (reflection)

Tags: java, generics, reflection, instantiation

I am trying to correctly understand how to use generics. I have been searching on it all morning but I get confused when the tutorials start adding multiple generic values, or using very abstract terms which I am still wrestling with.

I am still learning so any general advice is welcome, but I would like to specifically figure out the syntax for the method returning the generic class.

For example consider:

```
public class GenericsExample4 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Car car;
        Truck truck;

        car = buy(Car.class, 95);
        truck = buy(Truck.class, 45);
    }

    // HELP HERE!
    public static <T extends Vehicle> T buy(Class<T> type, int topSpeed) {

        // create a new dynamic class T . . . I am lost on syntax

        return null; // return the new class T. I am lost on the syntax here :(
    }
}

interface Vehicle {
    public void floorIt();
}

class Car implements Vehicle {

    int topSpeed;

    public Car(int topSpeed) {
        this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
    }

    @Override
    public void floorIt() {
        System.out.println("Vroom! I am going " + topSpeed + " miles per hour");
    }
}

class Truck implements Vehicle {
    int topSpeed;

    public Truck(int topSpeed) {
        this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
    }

    @Override
    public void floorIt() {
        System.out.println("I can only go " + topSpeed + " miles per hour");
    }
}
```

Can someone point out how to tie together this generic method?

Comment: That doesn't have much to do with generics. It has to do with reflection: you want to invoke a constructor on a class from the Class object representing this class. And since all your classes don't have the same constructors, it's besically impossible to do that in a generic way.

Comment: M1 Garand looks like you looking for trouble, jumping into Generics is always something that makes you struggle... at least is nice that you got a gun. I see you Generic Static Method, that accepts a Class Object whose parametric type must be of a subtype Vehicle. What you can do is try to build a instance of the Type represented by the `type` parameter using the Method `newInstance`, but your Vehicle classes must have an constructor without parameters... but still don't know if i am helping you... (Hi Nizet, long time don't see you here... i am wondering the same, hope the OP answer soon)

Comment: Okay, so to simplify, lets get rid of the Bike class and just deal with the Car and Truck. This is the real use case anyway. I'll update the post shortly.

Comment: @Mureinik gave you the answer.

Comment: Mmmmm... not so fast mate. i still don't get what is "Tie together this generic method"... what are you looking foward @M1Garand? Implement a Static Factory Method with bounded generics type?

Comment: The goal is to just get the syntax needed to complete the method. There will be no factory etc, these classes mimic the real use case which is much more abstract.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for the clarification. I'll add the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't generically call the `new` operator. What you can do is use reflection, under the assumption you know the constructor's parameters. For example, assuming every vehicle has a constructor which takes an `int` top speed:

```
public static <T extends Vehicle> T buy(Class<T> type, int topSpeed) {
    try {
        return type.getConstructor(Integer.TYPE).newInstance(topSpeed);
    } catch (Exception e) { // or something more specific
        System.err.println("Can't create an instance");
        System.err.println(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: WHOA... i never thought that you can create a instance with reflection using a parametrized constructor... i am out of date, i guess. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Beautiful!!!!! Thank you very much. Been beating my head against a wall for 4 hours . . . bleh! TYVM!